# JAXB2 annotations: troubles rendering a value in a list

Tags: java, marshalling, jaxb2, unmarshalling

Ihave some issues trying to render the following xml code with JAXB2 annotations:

```
....
<bizTransactionList>
    <bizTransaction type="urn:epcglobal:fmcg:btt:po">
        http://transaction.acme.com/po/54847
    </bizTransaction>
    <!--other entries -->
</bizTransactionList>
...
```

following the [documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_4-Mapping-a-Class-to-Simple-Content-or-Simple-Type-XmlValue.html#Mapping%20a%20Class%20to%20Simple%20Content%20or%20Simple%20Type%3a%20XmlValue) I managed to solve the problem as follows:
1) inside the class which owns the list I annotate the list getter this way

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="bizTransactionList")
@XmlElement(name="bizTransaction")
public List<BizTransaction> getBizTransactionList() {
    return bizTransactionList;
}
```

2) I create the BizTransaction class as follows

```
public class BizTransaction {

    private URI transactionId;
    private URI type;

    @XmlValue
    public URI getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(URI transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public URI getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(URI type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public BizTransaction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BizTransaction(URI transactionId, URI type) {
        super();
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

now the problem is that the attribute works fine, but the value (i.e. the transactionId variable) is always null.
Can you help me to spot the problem?

Comment: Is that a valid URI value if it has the leading and trailing newline and whitespace characters?

Comment: you definitely spot the point, thank you. maybe you could add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a reasonable model but your example XML is not valid because the leading and trailing white space around the `bizTransaction` element value means it is not a valid URI. If you said

```
    <bizTransaction type="urn:foo">http://transaction.acme.com/po/54847</bizTransaction>
```

then it would work as you expect.

Comment: that's the solution. Thank you very much!